# Remove elements from array based on relation between elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would one delete elements in an array, based on their relationship between each other?

Example:

```
  const array = [
    {
      id: 14098,
      parent: 14096,
    },
    {
      id: 14100,
      parent: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 14096,
      parent: 14100,
    },
  ];
```

So what would need to happen, is that I iterate through an array and I remove the parent element. When that happens all the child elements also get removed... and then the child elements of that child element.

Anyone know how I should tackle this?

Kind regards,

Ricardo

Comment: Can you share with us what you've tried so far?  SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

A basic example might look something like the following:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 14098, parent: 14096 },
  { id: 14099, parent: 14096 },
  { id: 14100, parent: 0 },
  { id: 14096, parent: 14100 },
  { id: 14200, parent: 0 },
  { id: 14210, parent: 14200 },
];

const delete_item_by_id = (array, id) => {
  const index = array.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
  if(index > -1) array.splice(index, 1);
};

const delete_item_and_children = (array, id) => {
  let queue = [id];
  delete_item_by_id(array, id);
  
  while(queue.length > 0) {
    let current = queue.pop();
    queue.push(...array.filter((item) => item.parent === current).map((item) => item.id));
    delete_item_by_id(array, current);
  }
};

delete_item_and_children(data, 14100);

console.log(data);
```

If your array is likely to be large you might want to use a map of some kind to quickly find the child items in your array, otherwise the filter call could be expensive.

If you can provide what you've done so far it would probably be worth it as others may have better advice for you.

Version using a map (without mutation):

```js
const data = [
  { id: 14098, parent: 14096 },
  { id: 14099, parent: 14096 },
  { id: 14100, parent: 0 },
  { id: 14096, parent: 14100 },
  { id: 14200, parent: 0 },
  { id: 14210, parent: 14200 },
];

const get_child_map = (array) =>
   array.reduce(
    (map, { id, parent }) => {
      let arr = map.get(parent);
      if(!arr) map.set(parent, arr = []);
      arr.push(id);
      return map;
    },
    new Map()
  );

const filter_out_item_and_descendents = (array, delete_id) => {
  const child_map = get_child_map(array);
  
  let remove = new Set([delete_id]);
  let queue = [delete_id];
  
  while(queue.length > 0) {
    let current = queue.pop();
    queue.push(...(child_map.get(current) ?? []));
    remove.add(current);
  }
  
  return array.filter(({ id }) => !remove.has(id));
};

console.log(filter_out_item_and_descendents(data, 14100));
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's true SO is not a free coding service, I was interested in this problem so here's my attempt. It finds all the elements to remove first, then removes them.

```js
let array = [{
    id: 14098,
    parent: 14096,
  },
  {
    id: 14100,
    parent: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 14096,
    parent: 14100,
  },
  {
    id: 14097,
    parent: 14000,
  },
  {
    id: 15098,
    parent: 14098,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    parent: 0,
  },
];



function getNewArrayWithRemovedIds(origArray, removeid) {
  let removearray = [removeid]
  const cb = (e) => (e.parent == removeid && removearray.push(e.id))
  let x = array
  while (x.length > 0) {
    x = origArray.filter(el => cb(el))
    if (x.length > 0) removeid = x[0].id
  }
  return origArray.filter(el => removearray.indexOf(el.id) == -1);
}
console.log(getNewArrayWithRemovedIds(array, 14100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as there are already working answers here, this is how I'd do it (**updated to fix the problem noted in the comments by that barbarian, Ben Stephens**):

```js
const getDescendentIds = (xs, target) => {
  const els = xs .filter (({parent}) => parent == target)
  return [target] .concat (els .flatMap (el => getDescendentIds (xs, el .id)))
}

const removeSubTree = (xs, target, ids = getDescendentIds (xs, target)) =>
  xs .filter (({id}) => !ids .includes (id))

const array = [{id: 14098, parent: 14096}, {id: 14100, parent: 0}, {id: 14096, parent: 14100 }]

console .log ('removing 14096', removeSubTree (array, 14096))
console .log ('removing 14098', removeSubTree (array, 14098))
console .log ('removing 14100', removeSubTree (array, 14100))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We break the problem into two steps.  First we (recursively) fetch the ids of the nodes descended from the one with our target id.  Then we filter the list to create a new list without those ids.

Note that this returns a *copy* of your original list without those values.  We do not mutate the original list.  We're not barbarians here!

#### Original Answer

This code was incorrect as Ben Stephens pointed out.  We need to use `filter` instead of `find`.

```js
const getDescendentIds = (xs, target) => {
  const el = xs .find (({parent}) => parent == target)
  return [target] .concat (el ? getDescendentIds (xs, el .id) : [])
}

const removeSubTree = (xs, target, ids = getDescendentIds (xs, target)) =>
  xs .filter (({id}) => !ids .includes (id))

const array = [{id: 14098, parent: 14096}, {id: 14100, parent: 0}, {id: 14096, parent: 14100 }]

console .log ('removing 14096', removeSubTree (array, 14096))
console .log ('removing 14098', removeSubTree (array, 14098))
console .log ('removing 14100', removeSubTree (array, 14100))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: @BenStephens: Thanks, fixed.  As to being a barbarian, I just hope the civilizing influence of the functional programmers in your midst can help you settle down!  ☺

Comment: Thank you sir, top of the Monad to you. (This is how I imagine functional programmers greet each other). More seriously though - whilst I feel like I'm a long way from really getting functional programming your posts here on SO and occasionally playing with Ramda have definitely helped add tools into my programming toolbox. Me less ugg now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it like this:

```js
function filterArray(array, id) {
    let previousLength = -1;
    let currentLength = array.length;
    let blacklist = [id];
    while (previousLength != currentLength) {
        previousLength = currentLength;
        array = array.filter((item) => {
            if ((blacklist.indexOf(item.parent) >= 0) || (blacklist.indexOf(item.id) >= 0)) blacklist.push(item.id);
            else return true;
        });
        currentLength = array.length;
    }
    return array;
}
  const array = [
    {
      id: 14098,
      parent: 14096,
    },
    {
      id: 14100,
      parent: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 14096,
      parent: 14100,
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      parent: 6
    }
  ];
  
  console.log(filterArray(array, 14100));
```

On each step we add the new elements to a blacklist until there are no new elements found.